# OAuth 2.0 API Authentication issue with Delhivery International

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication

I am connecting my application with Delhivery application using API, but I guess OAuth 2.0 is used there. I read a lot of suggestion on google and postman manual but unable to connect yet.

I recieved following output in token generation:

```
{
    "access_token": "***************", //base64 encoded detail of user
    "id_token": "****************", //base64 encoded detail of user
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

While using this token id or access token in the further API, then get issue:
not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: How do you send `access_token`? Contact their documentation, not Postman manual. Usually it should be added header `Authentication: Bearer {access_token}`

Comment: I used the same, got an error :
Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.

Comment: So fill in required headers

Comment: It's not working. Because it asks for credential parameter then. Which I have not.